# Need help in fetching all files in directory based on file extension using Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have folder having multiple '.txt' files along with one 'backup' folder. Now I want to fetch all files based on its '.txt' extension and wanted to move them in 'backup' folder. I am using Node.js.

Please let me know if anyone has any suggestions.

Regards,

Manan

Comment: Have you seen this module - https://github.com/isaacs/minimatch

Comment: So...combine `fs.readdir()` and `fs.rename()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sync solution, something like:

```
var dirPath = 'myDir/';
fs.readdirSync(dirPath).forEach(function(file){
   if(/\.txt$/.test(file)){  //If it's a txt file
       fs.renameSync(dirPath  + file, + 'backup/' + file)
   }
});
```

Cheers, from La Paz, Bolivia

Comment: One more issue I am facing is, I have file path whose name is randomly generated, e.g c:\my\file_123abcd1234.txt'. I need to open it so I am using fs.openSync('c:\my\file_' /a+/, a), but I am getting error in this expression. Please suggest, I am relatively new to javascript.

Comment: `fs.readdirSync` reads all files, even the ones with random names. I don't quite understand your problem..

Comment: There is only one file and I would like to open it but its name is partial dynamic so I am trying to make pattern and using it in fs.openSync but it is giving me an error. e.g fs.openSync('c:\my\file_' /a+/, a)

Answer (score 0):

Use fs.rename function http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_rename_oldpath_newpath_callback

```
fs.rename(oldPath, newPath, function(){
   console.log(oldPath + ' Moved to: ' + newPath);
});
```